# Should i put composite key columns next to each other?

Tags: postgresql

i have a table (a,b,c,d,e)

let's say my primary key is (a,b,e)

Is there a benefit to reordering my column definitions to (a,b,e,c,d) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The indexes are stored separately from the table. More benefit is found by arranging columns based on alignment requirements.